# Reflecting the name of 'this' in a Kotlin extension function

Tags: android, reflection, kotlin, kotlin-extension, kotlin-reflect

Is there a way to get the name of 'this' in an extension function?

```
fun Boolean?.persist() {

   if (this == null) return   // Do Nothing

   val nameOfVariable:String = //get the name of the variable? 

   // Persist variable
   PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).edit().putBoolean(nameOfVariable, this).apply()

}
```

Comment: Your `Boolean` isn't a variable, it's an object. A reference to the object may be stored in zero, one, two, ten, or any other number of variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you intend to do is not possible. You'd have to provide the `nameOfVariable` as a parameter. The extension function could be called on any value not being backed by a variable as well.

[Delegated Properties](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html) could be an alternative for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't do that. As workaround pass name as a parameter:

```
fun Boolean?.persist(name: String) {
    // ...
     PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).edit().putBoolean(name, this).apply()
}
```